# WPF Changing dependency property of custom control in XAML doesnt update XAML preview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

Here is code of my custom control  (it will be something like my own panel). And here I have textblock, property Text of this TextBlock is binded to dependency property which was declared in code-behind of this control

**Custom Panel - *ExtensibleViewPanel.xaml***

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="OrderTrackingSystem.Presentation.CustomControls.ExtensibleViewPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OrderTrackingSystem.Presentation.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             d:DesignHeight="950" d:DesignWidth="160">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="100" MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Header for each View -->
        <Border Grid.Row="0"
                Background="DeepPink">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="17"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="5"
                    Height="20"
                    Width="20">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ChevronRight" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <!-- ContentPresenter for User content -->
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ViewContent}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code-behind - *ExtensibleViewPanel.xaml.cs***

```cs
public partial class ExtensibleViewPanel : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Dependency properties

        /* DP to set panel header name */
        public string Caption
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Caption)));
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Caption",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(ExtensibleViewPanel),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


        /* DP to set panel content */
        public object ViewContent
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ViewContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ViewContentProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ViewContent", 
                typeof(object), 
                typeof(ExtensibleViewPanel), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        public ExtensibleViewPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

As you can see i set DataContent of MyControl to it's code-behind. And then the ***main problem***:

1. I Add my control to XAML

```xml
<ctrls:ExtensibleViewPanel Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Grid.RowSpan="4"
                                   Caption="XXL"
                                   Grid.Row="0">
</ctrls:ExtensibleViewPanel>
```

2. I dont run program, only set Caption dependency property to "XXL" and view of my control doesnt change (XAML preview), i want the same effect as when you add textblock and set property Text it into xaml designer, xaml designer of textblock show this text immediately

**When i start my program, my properties working good, and i see my Caption in opened program, but i want to understand how to update xaml preview after changing dependency property***

Comment: As a note, you do not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties. They already have their own change notification mechanism. Besides that, a control should not set its own DataContext, because that breaks the standard DataContext-based Bindings of its properties. In the control's XAML, bind to its own properties by RelativeSource Bindings, like `Text="{Binding Caption, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Comment: @Clemens thank you my friend, that was a right solution, you are the best :)